# Expectation of a log random variable

Tags: logarithms, taylor-expansion, expected-value

I have an equation that requires taking the natural log of a random variable. When trying to figure out how to evaluate the expression, I came across this paper:

Y. W. Teh, D. Newman and M. Welling (2006), [A Collapsed Variational Bayesian Inference Algorithm for Latent Dirichlet Allocation, NIPS 2006](https://papers.nips.cc/paper/2006/file/532b7cbe070a3579f424988a040752f2-Paper.pdf), 1353–1360.

They use a second order Taylor expansion around $_0=\mathbb{E}[x]$ to approximate $\mathbb{E}[\log(x)]$ to obtain

$$\mathbb{E}[\log(x)]\approx\log(\mathbb{E}[x])−\frac{\mathbb{V}[x]}{2\mathbb{E}[x]^2}$$

I can't seem to derive that equation and was wondering if someone might be able to help show that it is true? Also, does that result hold if instead we wanted to evaluate $\mathbb{E}[\log(-x)]$ where $x\in(-\infty,0)$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A second order Taylor expansion around $\mathbb{E}(x)$ gives

$$log(x)\approx log(\mathbb{E}(x))+\frac{1}{\mathbb{E}(x)}\times(x-\mathbb{E}(x))-\frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{\mathbb{E}(x)^2}(x-\mathbb{E}(x))^2$$

Take expectations

$$\mathbb{E}(log(x))\approx  \mathbb{E}(log(\mathbb{E}(x)))+\frac{1}{\mathbb{E}(x)}\times(\mathbb{E}(x)-\mathbb{E}(x))-\frac{1}{2}\frac{\mathbb{V}ar(x)}{\mathbb{E}(x)^2}$$

because the 2nd term vanishes and the expectation of a constant is the constant:

$$\mathbb{E}(log(x))\approx  log(\mathbb{E}(x))-\frac{1}{2}\frac{\mathbb{V}ar(x)}{\mathbb{E}(x)^2}$$

Comment: sure  there isn't a missing square in last element first row?

Comment: @tommik Thanks, I corrected that.

Comment: Does the solution hold irrespective of the domain of $x$? I.e., am I fine for $-x$ when $x<0$?

Comment: @JohnSmith Here $x>0$ but if $x<0$ it works similarly for $log(-x)$.

Comment: Maybe I'm being a bit slow, but I don't actually see how taking expectations results in that second equation. Don't I have a term that is $\mathbb{E}(\log(\mathbb{E}(x)))$? Where does that go?

Comment: Could you actually step through the expectations in your calculation?

Comment: @JohnSmith Is it clearer now?

Comment: Yup, that clears up everything! Thanks!